# Declare "Spock Like" Labels in Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

The Spock Framework, which is written in Groovy has such labels:

```
when:
stack.push(elem)

then:
!stack.empty
stack.size() == 1
stack.peek() == elem
```

I'd like to test my **pure** Groovy Scripts with Spock. This is not possible since you have to declare a class to use Spock. Since there's a way to use "assert" in Groovy to make inline Unit Tests I'd like to try something on my own with the labels Spock is using (when, expect, then, etc.)

Since Spock is written in Groovy - how to define such label statements by my own in my Groovy Script (Script only! No Class-Usage)

Comment: Spock transforms the sources at compile time, so there are two ways: 
1) transform sources by yourself, i.e. write own AST transformation (which involves classes & compiler magic);
2) let Spock do it for you.

Comment: The problem with Spock letting it do is that I want to use pure groovy script without class declaration. But Spock needs to have a class to instantiate my script class to actually call its functions.

Comment: Exactly. I'm telling that you cannot achieve this with Spock. If you want to go first way the best option is to check out Spock source and see how it does its magic.